# Codename One: Log file content with newlines on Android device

Tags: android, email, newline, codenameone

In my app I want to e-mail the log file content for debugging purposes. However, on an Android device newline characters (\n) show up as spaces and not real new-lines in the mail. (It works correctly on iPhones and in the simulator.) Can this be fixed or is there a workaround?

By the way, why does the simulator truncate the mail message text?

Edit: I just tested on a more recent tablet (2019 vs 2013) and the problem goes away.

Edit 2: Actually it depends on the e-mail client. Test case: create a Hello world project and change start() to:

```
public void start() {
    if(current != null){
        current.show();
        return;
    }

    Form hi = new Form("Test log", BoxLayout.y());

    Button b = new Button("Send log");
    b.addActionListener((ActionListener) (ActionEvent evt) -> {
        String text;
        try {
            byte[] read = com.codename1.io.Util.readInputStream(Storage.getInstance().createInputStream("CN1Log__$"));
            text = new String(read);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            text = ex.getMessage();
        }
        sendMessage("Log file", new Message(text), "");
    });
    hi.add(b);

    log("line 1");
    log("line 2");

    hi.show();
}
```

Testing on a Samsung Galaxy Tab A 10.1 this gives:

1) using (Samsung) Email client:

```
[EDT] 0:0:0,33 - Codename One revisions: 7dd4e7d08b3442d90959477ee52a5ae8c4361b29

[EDT] 0:0:0,36 - line 1
[EDT] 0:0:0,39 - line 2
```

2) using (Google) Gmail client:

```
[EDT] 0:0:0,33 - Codename One revisions: 7dd4e7d08b3442d90959477ee52a5ae8c4361b29 [EDT] 0:0:0,36 - line 1 [EDT] 0:0:0,39 - line 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the difference between Windows and Unix newline behavior. Android being unix uses plain `\n` whereas Windows uses `\r\n` as explained here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-newline

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. But this is a CN1 app on Android that sends a message through an Android e-mail client (Gmail). The message contains \n characters as it should (equal to System.getProperty("line.separator") for Android). The preview in Gmail (on the device), however, shows no newlines. This is all before the message is even sent (to a recipient on another OS such as Windows). So can you think of a workaround?

Comment: Also, why does the simulator truncate the mail message text?

Comment: Did you include content in the HTML email? It's possible you're seeing a preview of HTML email where <br> is expected. E-mail isn't really supported in the desktop build/simulator. This is a mock for debugging using mailto URLs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tested on a more recent tablet (2019 vs 2013) and the problem goes away (see Edit).

Comment: If this is inconsistent then we might be able to do something about it. Can you isolate a test case from this?

Comment: Please see Edit 2 in the original question.

Comment: Please file an issue with this case. I'm guessing the sendMessage method uses HTML incorrectly in this case